# C# nHibernate programmatically set db password

Tags: c#, nhibernate, connection, set, programmatically-created

I have a C# Windows Forms application.  We are using nHibernate version 2.1 with Castle.  We are installing our application in a secured vault.  Therefore, we need to store the password in encrypted format in the hibernate.cfg.xml file.  The C# code then decrypts the password.  How can I set the nHibernate connectin string password to the decrypted string value in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to use `Configuration.GetProperty` and `Configuration.SetProperty` to modify the configuration defined in your hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```
var configuration = new Configuration()
    .Configure();

const string connectionStringKey = "connection.connection_string";

string connectionString = configuration.GetProperty(connectionStringKey);
connectionString = Regex.Replace(
    connectionString,
    "Password=(.+);",
    DecryptPasswordMatch);

configuration.SetProperty(connectionStringKey, connectionString);
```

Where `DecryptPasswordMatch` is defined as:

```
static string DecryptPasswordMatch(Match m)
{
    string password = m.Groups[1].Value;

    password = /* some method that decrypts password */;

    return string.Format("Password={0}", password);
}
```

You'll have to change the regular expression slightly depending on your database engine (this should work for SQL Server).